# jquery choosen select validation messages are not dis-appering untill the form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

jQuery chosen select validation messages are not disappearing until the form submit. I applied required validation if I submit the form without choosing the value error message is displaying. But after I choose it is not disappearing as normal select boxes, it is staying until the form submit.

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ":hidden:not(.chosen-select)" });

$("#postJob").validate({
    rules: {
        skills:{
            required:true,
        },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please provide a running code snippets to understand the problem more easily.

jQuery validate messages are disappeared once the validation is fulfilled.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        "name": {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        "email": {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        "name": {
            required: "Please, enter a name"
        },
        "email": {
            required: "Please, enter an email",
            email: "Email is invalid"
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
        alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
        return false; // for demo
    }
});
```

});
Here is the fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/amwmedia/sw87W/

Comment: i want to required filed for multiple chosen

Comment: here is my fiddle code (message is not disappearing until the form submits) but i want to dismiss that message immediately after choosing a value just as a normal select box  http://jsfiddle.net/umh29brs/

Comment: similar can be implemented for select box also

Comment: Similar can be applied ..look at this following code.   http://jsfiddle.net/chadkuehn/D7K6U/

Comment: yes I know,my requirement is for chosen-select,in the fiddle link i attached ,message is not disclosing until clicking on submit button but i want to disclose it after immediate picking of chosen-select

Comment: if you have solved your problem acccept the answer and close it.cheers :)

Comment: Hi Sri,Is it possible to display validation messages on tooltip for chosen-select

Comment: Yes,https://github.com/Thrilleratplay/jQuery-Validation-Bootstrap-tooltip  I referred this link and integrated,it is working fine for other html elements,But for select2 it is not working as expected

Comment: then what is the problem ? is it not working ? although there are many plugins available for doing this. one of them is : - http://formvalidation.io/examples/using-tooltip-to-show-message/

Comment: var validobj =  $("#postJob").validate({
     
         err: {
             // You can set it to popover
             // The message then will be shown in Bootstrap popover
             container: 'tooltip'
         },
     errorClass: "myErrorClass",
       rules: {
        title: {
               required: true,
               minlength: 5,
               maxlength:250,
               common:true
           },
          }

Comment: provide a code snippet or fiddle for better understanding

Comment: For this fiddle apply tool tip only when mouse hover. I dont want to display tooltips by default after form submission  http://jsfiddle.net/chadkuehn/D7K6U/

Comment: jquery validations is not working for dynamic forms that are submitting through ajax

Ask